# Scroll to particular element without taking the offset

Tags: jquery, scroll, lazy-loading

There are n number of blocks in a page. Each block loads a image. To speed up the page, **lazyload** is used. Now there are some situations at which user wants to scroll to the 15th block on page load (similar to StackOverflow highlight and scroll to particular answer or comment).

I get the block number from the url, say `?page=15`.

And use,

```
$('html, body').stop().animate(
{
    scrollTop: $('section.block-holder[data-page='+gotopage+']').offset().top
}, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
```

Of course this should work flawlessly for all pages without lazyload. Now, I cannot remove lazyload, as a page may load up to 50 bigger size images. But on page load only 1 or 2 blocks stay inside the viewport and only the images of these blocks' were loaded. So the rest blocks have height 0.

How this problem can be solved?

Comment: Could you not scroll to the container before the picture loads?

Comment: @Marcel: It scrolls, but not to the aimed container. Speaking in detail, say I need to scroll to 15th container. On page load only 1st and 2nd images are loaded. So the top offset of 15th box will be `x`. When the scrolling is started, 3rd, 4th.... images started to load and thus the corresponding blocks take the height of images inside it. Now `x` will be invalid for 15th block.

Comment: It would be great if you can create a fiddle.. Blindly, I guess you can use `while` as your condition, so it will try to animate to the 15th block..

Comment: @Viswalinga Surya S I would suggest a fixed height for images or a placeholder loading gif to keep the container at a fixed height.

Comment: @Marcel: The problem is the images are of various heights. So fixed height will make the images to overflow!

Comment: @user3003216: Fiddle is difficult, however I will try to show a temporary webpage!

Comment: Give the images a fixed height. If you set them all to have the class thumbnail which has a height of say 100px, each image will be 100px tall. If you do not set the width, it will default to auto which means the picture's aspect ratio will be preserved.

Comment: @Marcel: I understand your point. The scenario is all the images are 700 pixels in width. However the height is not the same. One will be 1000 pixels height and another will be 1468 pixels high and so on. And there comes the problem. Even if I set `min-height` for the container, the offset will be wrong!

Comment: @Viswalinga Surya S I don't think so. I just did the exact same thing for an upload system.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the size of all your images or their containers before they are loaded. Then using lazy load you can fill the `src` tag and load the image.